# Could not launch Espresso Test Recorder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I am trying to run Espresso test recorder on an android app I need to test. however i am unable to even run test recorder because I keep getting an error saying that it can't be invoked.

Here is the error being displayed when attempting to run espresso test recorder:

[image]

I believe that it has to do with my android studio environment, but i had also reset the ide to the default settings and now don't really know what to do as there isn't much resources or relatable content to this issue. If any senior android developers or some one with a good amount of knowledge about espresso or android development can provide some insight it would be helpful.